# How to start firefox in fullscreen mode?

Tags: firefox, fullscreen

How do I start Firefox 4 in fullscreen mode (the one activated by pressing <kbd>F11</kbd>)?

Answer (score 32):

on Linux (works on debian jessie):

```
firefox -url http://superuser.com &
xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible --class "Firefox" windowactivate key F11
```

firefox line - starts firefox with url and detaches from terminal ("&"). "&" is required, otherwise following script won't execute while firefox exits.

xdotool line searches window with partial name "Firefox" (partial name of running app window can be determinated by xwininfo), activates firefox window, sends key F11 to Firefox.

This code is bit better than YumYumYum's solution (sending key only when firefox actualy started. sleep is not really usable approach, cause can miss firefox on slow/overloaded computers or too late on fast computers)

sorry for late answer (missed 6 years)

Comment: Works like a charm on Ubuntu 16

Comment: If you don't want to fork Firefox off you can simply invert the order of these commands and `xdotool` will still dutifully wait for Firefox to show up before it presses F11.

Comment: @Ekevoo can you give an example?

Comment: @eekfonky `xdotool $PARAMS & firefox -url http://superuser.com`

Answer (score 7):

Many useful plugins mentioned in other answers, but not many that work on Firefox 57 (Quantum). If you're stuck, try [ForceFull](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/forcefull/). For bonus points, it goes fullscreen instantly on startup by default. No config necessary to get that behavior.

Comment: That combined with `--kiosk` did the job!

Answer (score 6):

Create a new [profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_Manager) by running:

```
firefox -ProfileManager
```

Run firefox with the new profile, move to full screen using <kbd>F11</kbd> and then close it by <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f4</kbd>

Each time you will use this profile it will be opened in full screen.

Comment: Do not forget the "-no-remote" option  if you already have a running instance of Firefox: "firefox -ProfileManager -no-remote"

Comment: After making the profile and closing Firefox in full screen mode you can use "firefox -P 'Session Name' -no-remote" to start Firefox in full screen mode.

Comment: Does not work for me (in 2016)

Comment: @KarelBílek just installed it and it works!

Comment: @MichalSzyndel interesting! I will try it again

Comment: Does not work on Firefox 55.0.2 on Arch Linux

Comment: Doesn't work at Firefox 56.0.2 (in 2017)

Answer (score 5):

### Command Line

Firefox [command line option](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=654650) `-fullscreen` didn't work for me:

```
"firefox.exe" -url http://superuser.com -fullscreen
```

- MDN - [Command Line Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Command_Line_Options)
- MozillaZine - [Command line arguments](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments)

---

### Extension

But the use of [R-kiosk 0.9.0](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/r-kiosk/?src=search) extension by [Kimmo Heinaaro](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/user/6189/) works like a charm.

> Real Kiosk is a Firefox extension that defaults to full screen, disables all menus, toolbars, key commands and right button menus. Alt+Home still takes you home.

Comment: Does not work anymore (in 2016)

Comment: @KarelBílek just installed it and it works!

Answer (score 4):

Also you can try to use the following command:

`firefox -kiosk 'http://your.url'`

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-enterprise-kiosk-mode

Answer (score 1):

If you're using firefox 3 you can use [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/full-fullscreen/) extension. It allows fullscreen on start. Tons of others do as well, see [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/search/?q=kiosk&cat=all&x=0&y=0).

I'm not aware of a command-line switch though.

Answer (score 1):

Full-screen me dad!

```
$ cat /var/tmp/firefoxfullscreen.sh 
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0.0 # eye
cat > /var/tmp/index.html << \EOF
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3" />
<style>
html { 
  background: url("http://192.168.0.142:7007/video/vnc.jpeg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
EOF

ps aux | grep firefox | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9; # kill me
firefox "/var/tmp/index.html" & # leave me alone
sleep 5 # hehehe
xdotool key F11 # hit full screen
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try [R-KIOSK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/r-kiosk/) with work really good.

Comment: I would give you +1 if you would explain a little more if you explain a little more what it is, what it does and what your personal experience is.

Comment: I agree with @MadMike. +1 after a nice explanation :-)

Comment: This extension is not available anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I used the useful solution of @Zero in **Raspberry PI 3b**.
It works well, but sometimes the Firefox is not "ready" to receive the F11 keypress event.

Then I did a little change: a delay before Window activation and F11 key press:

```sh
firefox -url http://superuser.com &
xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible --class "Firefox" windowactivate key F11
```

Comment: Where's the delay? This is an exact copy of Zero's answer

Answer (score 1):

I cannot install `xdotools`, and for me, starting firefox in kiosk mode alone did not open it in fullscreen and still showed bars and the list of open tabs.

```bash
firefox -kiosk -private-window [URL]
```

does the trick for me, it shows the website I enter in fullscreen mode.
Even though I was starting firefox in kiosk mode, I sometimes received a firefox popup on the things that were updated (new colortheme etc). Launching firefox with the flag `--new-window` helped me avoid these messages:

```bash
firefox -kiosk -private-window [URL] --new-window
```

Tested with Mozilla Firefox 103.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

After scouring the web for days, I found the [Auto Fullscreen](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autofullscreen/) plugin.

It's just a simple script which does what it says.