# How can I get chromium-browser to run fullscreen (not kiosk) in 12.04?

Tags: firefox, chromium, browser, fullscreen

I have created a restricted user which logs in automatically and Chromium runs the default home page with the screen starting maximized but I want it to run in fullscreen (F11) mode. I tried kiosk mode but I don't want to be that restricted and it doesn't seem to behave properly at all (keyboard is almost broken).

I would consider digital signage software but don't really want anything client/server. I just want the machine to boot straight into fullscreen mode. Does this work for firefox?

Comment: check [How to start firefox in fullscreen mode?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36287/how-to-start-firefox-in-fullscreen-mode) and [Launch Google Chrome in Fullscreen mode](http://superuser.com/questions/430862/windows-launch-google-chrome-in-fullscreen-mode)

Comment: Please clarify if you want to have full desktop environment (e.g. ability to switch to other applications) or just a browser running?  The answer might differ.

Comment: I don't really care but for the sake of argument, let's say I want the ability to switch to other applications. That was what I meant by (not kiosk).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What about using xdtool http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/xdotool.1.html

```
xdotool key F11
```

this will work for any kind of standard focused window. Include it into start-up script.

don't have xdotool?

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

in combination with `--start-maximized` (which does not do F11, just maximized window) on command line can fulfil your needs

shell script should make the job

```
chromium-browser --start-maximized
sleep 5
xdotool key F11
```

Firefox differs only in `-fullscreen` command line option. The option for F11 mode is missing as well. But consider to use Firefox and Rkiosk extension https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/r-kiosk/?src=search or the Fullscreen extension https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/full-fullscreen/

If the script stucks at `chromium-browser` invocation - add a & at the end:

```
chromium-browser --start-maximized &
...
```

Answer (score 51):

For people finding this now, you can start Chromium fullscreen from the command line by executing:

```
chromium-browser --app=http://example.com --start-fullscreen
```

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: better than the default answer

Comment: better than my answer from 2013, which was the only solution because the -start-fullscreen was not present in chromium browser as I remember.

Comment: can confirm that this still works (tested with Chromium 65.0.3325.181), although it is still not listed in the chromium-browser man page (after 3+ years)

Comment: Still works, here in 2020.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [this](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/chromium-immer-maximiert-oeffnen/) and other sources, you could try the following, with good chances of success :-)

```
cp /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop
nano ~/.local/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop
```

(you may alternatively want to use `gksu` and the editor of your choosing)

Now, simply add **`-start-maximized`** to the line saying **`exec`** in **`chromium-browser.desktop`**, save and you're done.

Comment: Combine with RadicalRaid's answer and change the line to `Exec=chromium-browser --start-fullscreen %U`, or `Exec=chromium-browser --start-fullscreen --app=http://example.com %U`. Include `--kiosk` flag to avoid the message `Press F11 to exit full-screen` (from [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69204/open-chromium-full-screen-on-start-up)). I like this solution best.