# Display a graphical web page on Ubuntu Server

Tags: xorg, xserver

I have a raspberry pi running Ubuntu Server connected to a large display that needs to display a webpage containing HTML and CSS to show information is the lobby at my workplace.
If possible, I would like to have the webpage run in a browser like chromium in a basic x session, no proper desktop environment or anything.

Here’s what I’ve tried:
Installing xorg and Openbox, which worked, but I’d prefer to not have to run the browser in a window manager/desktop environment, if possible.

In a nutshell, I need to run a single graphical web browser full screen in a basic x session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question:
To do this, we will run Chromium in Kiosk mode.
First, install chromium and xorg:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install chromium-browser xorg
```

Now, you can start Chromium in kiosk mode with this command:

```
startx /usr/bin/chromium-browser —-kiosk <website>
```

You would replace “website” with the website you would like to visit. To exit kiosk mode, do <kbd>alt+f4</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine two options to do this.

1. You can directly launching a program (e.g. Firefox, Chrome) from terminal by passing it as a parameter to `startx`
2. You can use the Kiosk mode of a browser that supports it (Chrome?) Or the full screen mode of any browser, where you set the default home page to the URL that you want to show.

See for more help:

1. [How to start firefox in fullscreen mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36287/how-to-start-firefox-in-fullscreen-mode)
2. https://superuser.com/questions/219511/browser-instead-of-window-manager

Comment: How would I pass Chrome as a parameter with startx? Would I need to install anything more than xorg?

Comment: I found this that describes how to start chrome in kiosk mode: https://superuser.com/questions/219511/browser-instead-of-window-manager. I’m testing it with Chromium now.

Comment: I got it working with Chromium kiosk mode. I submitted an answer and I will mark it correct in 48 hours, when it will let me do that.

Answer (score 1):

[Here suggests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32454/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-web-browser-while-no-kde-or-gnome-is-installed) it's doable. However, it would also depend on what your web page requires. Is it simple HTML+CSS? Then you don't even need the heavyweight Chromium and can use a lighter browser such as [Midori](http://midori-browser.org)  [Falkon](https://falkon.org/about)  [Min](http://minbrowser.github.io/min) (reviewed)  or [a few others](http://linux.com/tutorials/5-minimal-web-browsers-linux).

Comment: There will be embedded html5 video, so it will probably have to be chromium.

Comment: I got it working with Chromium kiosk mode. I submitted an answer and I will mark it correct in 48 hours, when it will let me do that.